# Can I stop the replicas of a DynamoDB global table from synchronising?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-global

I am having DynamoDB table in a specific region but the data it contains support application instances in multiple regions. I want to create a DDB per region setup without downtime.
In the end I want to have multiple instances running, each one in it's own region with it's own regional database table, but I also want the two tables to be in sync while the migration is rolling out.

I know that I can use DynamoDB streams with lambda to keep the two tables in sync for as long as I need, but I wonder if there's an easier way.

The idea is to add the extra region to the existing table, making it a global table. This will allow each local instance to use it's local database while also keeping the data in sync among regions.
But I don't want to maintain a global table for ever since after the migration is completed there's no reason to keep the replicas in sync.

So, is it possible to stop the replicas of a global table from syncing?
Is is possible to split a global table to it's local parts?
I couldn't find anything in the docs, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Probably best not to use the word 'Local' here. When you say you have "a Local DynamoDB table", you presumably mean that you have a DynamoDB table in the closest AWS region to you (as opposed to "I am using [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html)").

Comment: In terms of a solution, I think I would simply treat these as two distinct tables: one global and the other not. Once your migration is complete, you switch your app over to the appropriate non-global table. You'd have to sync its contents, obviously, and you could use a one-time export or potentially DynamoDB Streams to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate it because the wording in the docs is a bit confusing. It states that the table gets removed from the replication group when the region becomes inaccessible, but all the aws API calls talk about deleting replicas. Will get back once I have more info :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I deleted the answer. You can provide your own based on what you found.

Comment: So far the answer I have is "you can't" but I'll leave it open in case I discover something new

Answer (score 0):

Global Tables FAQ state that you can't pause replication: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/dynamodb-global-tables/faq.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).